# Jquery function firing in safari but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I scroll to the page to the top when the page loads with `document.ready()`. However in Chrome this function only runs when I'm on the page and I refresh it.

If I access the page by typing the link in the address bar, the function doesn't run. If I access the page from a link from another page, it also doesn't run. The only way it runs 100% of the time in Chrome is if I'm on the page and I refresh it.

However, in Safari, the function runs 100% every single time by accessing the page from a link, typing it in the address bar, on reload.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (location.hash) {               // do the test straight away
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);         // execute it straight away
          setTimeout(function() {
              window.scrollTo(0, 0);     // run it a bit later also for browser compatibility
          }, 1);
          //location.reload();
      }
});
```

This actually also works in Safari without putting it in `document.ready()` but then again not in Chrome.

Does anybody know what causes this and if this is possible to fix?
I've had this problem before and it was extremely frustrating.

Comment: How would the page not be at the top already when going directly to the page by typing in the url, etc?

Comment: There could be an anchor (#) in the URL I guess.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You haven't explained behavior you see or how you know function doesn't run.

Comment: Could be the jquery version or the route,

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log` statements and/or `debugger;` to ensure your code is running as expected?

Comment: Sorry the lack of info. Yes,  the url contains an anchor(#)  that is used to open up a tab of the category that the content belongs to(bootstrap tabs). But having an anchor(#) link scrolls the page down to the element with that ID causing the page to load at that scroll position of that element. That's what this code is for. It does run perfectly in safari. In Chrome it shows no error   but it handles it differently or something because it does run but only if I refresh the page.

Comment: I think I have found the problem what's causing this. When I use the setTimeout() function, I have '1' millisecond as the second parameter. This seems to be too fast for Chrome to fire of the window.ScrollTo() function. However when I put a console log in in the SetTimeOut, it is able to display that log. When I set the time to a minimum of 200ms it does work in Chrome and is able to fire the window.scroll() function. But the problem now is that it's not fast enough. Is there a way to reduce this time lower than 200ms?

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the setTimeout delay time 20ms or more then 20ms, it may be because of 1ms is too short time of interval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (location.hash) {        
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, 0);}, 20);
}
});
```

Comment: The lowest I can go, while having it working is 200ms. However when I use (window).load I can even get it down to 115ms while working but still nowhere near 20ms. As soon as I go lower than 115ms I won't work everytime and when I set it to 20ms, it just ignores the window.ScrollTo() but it's still able to fire console logs and alerts.

Comment: Using timeouts with magic "this number makes it work" values is a code smell. Better to keep digging in to figure out the problem. If you absolutely can't make it work without a magic number, be sure to document the reason for it clearly in a comment.

Comment: Sorry I stopped trying to do it this way and decided to it another way, completely cutting out the setTimeOut() function as it was too un consistent in different browser, thanks for help tho people.